# MVC как организовать работу программиста и верстальщика

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, mvc

Я пишу на JS вэбинарную комнату.
Чистый typescript + jquery. Никаких реактов итд. 
В зависимости от новых задач интерфейс дополняется. 
Верстальщику желательно отдавать проект для доработки в формате html + css + js файлики. Но у меня совсем все по-другому устроено, MVC. 
Нет свалки кода в одном месте, блоки html должны быть отделены друг от друга.

Получается я уже 3 раза немного переписал свой код чтобы натянуть верстку после того как 2 разных верстальщика дорабатывали верстку.

Сейчас чтобы добавить хоть какой-то чекбокс в верстку верстальщиком, мне нужно выслать ему html + css, выбрать некоторые из своих js классов, подключить их к странице чтобы заработало, к примеру, 
добавление сообщения в текстовый чат после нажатия на кнопку. После изменений в js верстальщиком мне нужно будет их найти и применить к своим production классам Мне кажется такой подход излишне трудоемкийм.

Как технически в таких ситуациях поступать ? 
Полностью весь код проекта мы не можем показать верстальщику

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таких случаях нужно явно разделять что относиться к фронтенду, а что к бекенду и использовать лучшие принципы в виде SOLID, GRASP.

Опишу набор советов которые использую сам.

1. Разрабатывай модульно. Если нужна таблица которая отображает пользователей, сделайте отдельную таблицу, и методы которые отвечают за сохранения, удаления, редактирование вынеси таким образом, что бы они возвращали объекты с только нужными полями, для того что бы отобразить эту таблицу. Вообще не думая, что там на бекенде. Потом эти методы можно будет поменять реальными запросами. В функциональной парадигме есть принцип, что функция зависит только от входных параметров, так и модуль у тебя должен зависить только от входных параметров.
2. MVC - Не гибкий монолит. Куда лучше связка Json API + Ajax. Твоему фронту придется только работать с апишкой и не думать, про то как влить код в проект, все что он по факту напишет, уже будет работать в любом месте программы.

Переписать всё на Json API + ajax будет куда быстрее, чем в MVC пытаться разделить обязанности между фронтом разработчиком и бекенд.